# Google Gmail - "The conversation that you requested could not be loaded"

Tags: google-api

It seems like a link like:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/1648ec7930317b4a

Displays 'The conversation that you requested could not be loaded'. The email with that id is clearly in the inbox (retrieved via https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

Is this the correct way to link to an email by id?

Edit: I should also mention that sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Comment: I think that when you provide the detail flow you did, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The api gives me an id and threadId for the email... how do I link to an email with that id? I can't find documentation from google on how to do that but have seen  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/{ id } as the most common approach.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. You want to retrieve a direct link of gmail using message ID. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

To overcome try setting:

```
Gmail / Settings / Conversation view=on
```

Seems to me as a bug

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem. Your reading pane is not enabled. I had the same problem this morning. I didn't change anything. It just started happening. Good luck, I hope this helps. **You can fix this by:**

1. Log into your gmail account
2. Go to settings -> See all settings
3. Click the "Inbox" Tab
4. Reading pane: "Enable reading pane"